# Allocating random values from a list to missing column values, in Python

Tags: python, random

I have a two column dataframe

```
id  content

1    100
2    101  
3
4    100
5
6    104
```

Now for missing values of content , I want to randomly assign  content from the list of plausible values `content_list=range(100,111)`

So for `id=3` and `id=5` I want to populate content by any random value from content_list.

I used `random.choice`, but missing something here:

```
def f(list):
   return random.choice(list)

if data.content.isnull():
    data['content']=data['content'].map(f,content_list)
```

Comment: Does `f(content_list)` not work? You may need to make `content_list` a list with `list(content_list)`.

Comment: If statement only does not work. Passing list is not a problem. We can pass it anyway. Just downvoting the question would not help.

Comment: I didn't downvote. Maybe if you said it was the if statement we could help you easier?

Comment: can u suggest any other way?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
data[data.content.isnull()].apply(lambda x: x['content'] = random.randint(100,111))
```

Comment: x.content would not work. We cannot access a column in this way!!

Comment: It gives the following error "SyntaxError: lambda cannot contain assignment"